# asp.net trying to create a log file for my web app

Tags: c#, permissions

I am trying to put a log.txt file on the root of my application and would like to write to it. But it seems like this is not working. Thanks for any help.

Error message (I dont think i am writing to the proper file, this is local host by the way. I would like this to work if its local or on the webhost):

> Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\DevServer\10.0\log.txt' is denied.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.

This is my code:

```
 public static void LogErrorMessage(Exception e)
    {
        using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("log.txt"))
        {
             Log(e.ToString(),w);
             w.Close();
        }

    }



private static void Log(String logMessage, TextWriter w)
        {
            w.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
            w.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
                DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
            w.WriteLine("  :");
            w.WriteLine("  :{0}", logMessage);
            w.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
            // Update the underlying file.
            w.Flush();
        }
```

Comment: make sure that the application pool user has write permissions to the directory that you are writing to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need:

```
public static void LogErrorMessage(Exception e, string Directory)
{
    using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(Directory + "/log.txt"))
    {
         Log(e.ToString(),w);
         w.Close();
    }

}
```

ASPX Class

```
public void Page_Load()
   {
      Logger.LogErrorMessage(ex, Server.MapPath("~"));

   }
```

Comment: How do you use map path on a class? This is not a asp server class

Comment: Try `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()` method. No change method sign.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Environment.CurrentDirectory` to get your running folder.

Your code now attempts to write to the web server runtime folder (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0`).

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the full path of your log.txt file, you can use web.config to fetch the directory path.

Comment: Yes but then I would have to change it if I upload to a host.

Comment: Keeping Directory path in web.config allows you to change it even after you publish it on web server, so this should help you. You can have one path in local/ test environment and different on Production server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find which user is running your IIS site (find the user in your site's app pool with IIS Manager).

You must give permissions to this user to read/write in the folder where you're trying to create your log.txt file.

The error is ablolutely clear "access is denied".

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), implementing it is quite simple.

First Download and add Reference the NLog in your Project.

and Create NLog.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >

    <targets>

        <target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/Logs/site.log"
         layout="${date}: ${message}" />

        <target name="eventlog" xsi:type="EventLog" source="Dealing Errors Nlog" log="Application"
        layout="${date}: ${message} ${stacktrace}" />


    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="file" />

        <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="eventlog" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="eventlog" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

In Global.asax

```
private NLogLogger GetLog()
        { return new NLogLogger(); }
```

Creat one class named Log.cs :

```
public static class Log
    {

        public static ILogger GetLogger()//return the interface
        {
            return new NLogLogger();
        }
    }
```

Create other class named NLogger :

```
public class NLogLogger : ILogger
    {
        private Logger _logger; //NLog

        public NLogLogger()
        {
            _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        }

        public void Info(string message)
        {
            _logger.Info(message);
        }

        public void Warn(string message)
        {
            _logger.Warn(message);
        }

        public void Debug(string message)
        {
            _logger.Debug(message);
        }

        public void Error(string message)
        {
            _logger.Error(message);
        }

        public void Error(Exception x)
        {
            Error(LogUtility.DealingException(x));
        }

        public void Fatal(string message)
        {
            _logger.Fatal(message);
        }

        public void Fatal(Exception x)
        {
            Fatal(LogUtility.DealingException(x));
        }
    }
```

and cread on Interface ILogger :

```
 public interface ILogger
    {

        void Info(string message);


        void Warn(string message);


        void Debug(string message);


        void Error(string message);


        void Error(Exception x);


        void Fatal(string message);


        void Fatal(Exception x);
    }
```

and finally one class LogUtility:

```
 public class LogUtility
    {

        public static string DealingException(Exception x)
        {
            Exception logException = x;
            if (x != null)
            {
                logException = x;
            }

            string strErrorMsg = Environment.NewLine + "URL ERROR:\t" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;

            strErrorMsg += Environment.NewLine + "URL:\t" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;

            strErrorMsg += Environment.NewLine + "Message:\t" + (logException.Message != null ? logException.Message : "Not Found");


            strErrorMsg += Environment.NewLine + "Source:\t" + (logException.Source != null ? logException.Source : "Not Found");


            strErrorMsg += Environment.NewLine + "Stack Trace:\t" + (logException.StackTrace != null ? logException.StackTrace : "Not found");

            strErrorMsg += Environment.NewLine + "Destination URL:\t" + (logException.TargetSite.ToString() != null ? logException.TargetSite.ToString() : "Not found");

            strErrorMsg += Environment.NewLine;
            strErrorMsg += Environment.NewLine;
            return strErrorMsg;
        }
    }
```